# How to download a website for offline use while preserving a search feature?

Tags: backup, website

There's a website I'd like to download since it's had some problems lately. I tried the usual way with HTTrack and that worked for clickable links, but the search box on the site still refers to the original website and searching anything brings me back to the original site. Is there a way to make the search box work on the download?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The search feature is using software on the server that indexes the pages and creates a searchable catalogue of what the site contains. When you click "search" your website asks that software to give a list of pages containing that term.

Most HTML pages are, to put it bluntly, just dumb text. They have javascript for dynamic element *within that page* but those scripts cannot simply search other pages within the website because outside of links on their own page they have no idea about the contents of the entire website.

For a script on the browser client to index and search a website it would have to basically go through every link on its own page, somehow load the text of every page, run scripts in case there is something important, and then follow all those links and so on. Every client that tried to do a search would end up essentially requesting the entire website and it would be slow, inefficient and a waste because they might only want one of a thousand web pages.

The server on the other hand has all the page contents right there, either as html files or stored in a database and they can be indexed locally and without having a lot of wasted bandwidth. A client sends a request of "do you have a page containing `blargh`" and the server returns a list rather than the whole site.

You *could* have a client-side javascript based search tool, but again it would waste bandwidth and may not be worth the effort. It would require the server to have created some kind of search index of the whole site that the client could download, which it *might* have to do for its own search tool if it is not already provided by the database. The downside there is that that index could again be very large and would potentially be changing very often. Browser caching could mean that a page gets updated and someone does a search while they have an old version of the index so when they search they get no results even while browsing a page with that exact search result on it.